# The flutter tool cannot access the file

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, permissions, windows-10

I try to run the Flutter project but there is an error

```
Flutter failed to write to a file at
"C:\Users\Dell\flutter-development\projects\flutter_complete_guide\ios\Runner\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h". The flutter
tool cannot access the file.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current
user.
```

Versions:

Flutter 1.22.4,

Windows 10

I tried to create a Flutter project with cmd and android-studio but the result is the same.

I gave full permissions for ALL(Including Dell user) for flutter-sdk directory, flutter project and their subdirectories also.

Once try to build project from scratch with **flutter create myapp**
get next error

```
PS C:\src1\project> flutter create myapp
Recreating project myapp...
  myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
Failed to send crash report due to a network error: SocketException: OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5, address = clients2.google.com, port = 63568
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'C:\src1\project\myapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png', path =
'C:\src1\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\templates\app\android.tmpl\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Flutter failed to write to a file at
"C:\Users\Dell\flutter-development\projects\flutter_complete_guide\ios\Runner\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h". The flutter
tool cannot access the file.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current
user.
```

Make sure that you have ownership rights over the flutter installation folder. Check [this](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer) out.

```
OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5
```

> Error 5: Access denied is a known issue on Windows 10. This error
> prevents you from installing software on your computer and accessing
> or modifying certain files.
>
> The reason for this issue is the non-availability of the permissions.
> Windows 10 will prevent you from installing if you don’t have the
> Administrator privileges or if your account is not the administrator
> account.

[Getting administrator privileges for your account on the computer solves this problem.](https://appuals.com/fix-error-5-access-denied-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I spent 5 days just to fix this issue.

- i reset my windows 10 and it didn't work.
- i upgrade to windows 11 and hoping it might takeover the permission
  or anything, but still didn't work.
- until i tried to backup my flutter project to google drive and then
  redownload it. it ends up work.

*i guess to fix this issue you just need to reset the folder attribute by recreating every file. and in my case through cloud storage*.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the folder mentioned by the error is hidden.